# Full Clone VDI with VBoxManage.exe

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine, clone

What is the command-line switch that I should use to create a full clone of a given vdi?

I want to be able to clone the virtual machine such that all files, folders and applications are also copied to the clone - similar to performing a "full clone" from the GUI application.

The command I am aware of is:

VBoxManage.exe clonevdi source.vdi target.vdi

But this only appears to copy half of the vdi file, how do I clone the full image?

Comment: What does "appears to copy half of the vdi file" mean?

Comment: The size of the Disk I set to 80gb, but only 45gb is copied.

Comment: You should edit the question to include that information. Also, is something missing, or is it just that blocks of zero bytes were not written to the new image?